# SpecFlow throwing error Input string was not in a correct format

Tags: c#, specflow

I have the following line in the feature file

```
When user changes the ATM: Limit Offline to any amount between '$150 and $520'
```

which generates the following definition

```
[When(@"user changes the ATM: Limit Offline to any amount between '(.*)'")]
public void WhenUserChangesTheATMLimitOfflineToAnyAmountBetween(string p0)
{
    _cardOfflineLimitScard.ResetOfflineLimit("ATM");
}
```

I don't need the string p0, but  if I remove it manually, the step remains bound but during run time I get an error:

> Input string not in a correct format

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the dollar sign characters. The string gets interpreted as a regular expression, and the `$` matches the end of the string in Regex.

```
[When(@"user changes the ATM: Limit Offline to any amount between \$([0-9]+) and \$([0-9]+)")]
public void WhenUserChangesTheATMLimitOfflineToAnyAmountBetween(decimal lowAmount, decimal highAmount)
{
    ...
}
```

Now you can use the numbers in your step definition if you want.

Reference: [Using Regular Expressions with The Microsoft .NET Framework](https://www.regular-expressions.info/dotnet.html).